# Opengl macos fail

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I have problem. I wrote the code on clear opengl and c++ without any libraries(glut, glew...) but it doesnt work.
Function displayCB display polygon with

```
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
     glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
     glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
     glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
     glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
   glEnd();
```

and dont display two polygone with

```
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
     glLoadIdentity();                                  // Reset The Current Modelview Matrix
        glTranslatef(-1.5f,0.0f,-6.0f);                     // Move Left 1.5 Units And Into The Screen 6.0
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                              // Drawing Using Triangles
            glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top
            glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Left
            glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right
        glEnd();                                            // Finished Drawing The Triangle
        glTranslatef(3.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                       // Move Right 3 Units
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);                                  // Draw A Quad
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top Left
            glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top Right
            glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right
            glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Left
        glEnd();
```

Can you help me?

COMPILE WITH:       g++ -g -o opengl1 opengl1.cxx -lGLU -lGL -lX11

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
    #define GLX_GLXEXT_PROTOTYPES
    #include <GL/gl.h>
    #include <GL/glu.h>
    #include <GL/glx.h>

    struct MyWin
    {
      Display  *display;
      Window    win;
      bool      displayed;
      int       width;
      int       height;
    };


    const int   WIN_XPOS    = 256;
    const int   WIN_YPOS    = 64;
    const int   WIN_XRES    = 600;
    const int   WIN_YRES    = 600;
    const int   NUM_SAMPLES = 4;


    MyWin        Win;


    double elapsedMsec( const struct timeval &start, const struct timeval &stop )
    {
      return ( ( stop.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec  ) * 1000.0 +
               ( stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec ) / 1000.0 );
    }


    double elapsedUsec( const struct timeval &start, const struct timeval &stop )
    {
      return ( ( stop.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec  ) * 1000000.0 +
           ( stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec ) );
    }


    /// check() - Check for GL errors, and report any queued

    void check( const char hdr[] = "" )
{
  int err;

  while ( ( err = glGetError() ) != GL_NO_ERROR )
    fprintf( stderr, "OpenGL Error at %s: %s\n", hdr, gluErrorString(err) );
}



void displayCB()
{
  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

  //---------------------------------------------------
  // FIXME: Insert GL draw code here
  //---------------------------------------------------
  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  glLoadIdentity();                                 // Reset The Current Modelview Matrix
    glTranslatef(-1.5f,0.0f,-6.0f);                     // Move Left 1.5 Units And Into The Screen 6.0
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                              // Drawing Using Triangles
        glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Left
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right
    glEnd();                                            // Finished Drawing The Triangle
    glTranslatef(3.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                       // Move Right 3 Units
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                                  // Draw A Quad
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top Left
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top Right
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Left
    glEnd();            
  // glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  //   glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
  //   glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
  //   glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
  //   glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
  // glEnd();
  // Display it
  glXSwapBuffers( Win.display, Win.win );

  check( "displayCB()" );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void keyboardCB( KeySym sym, unsigned char key, int x, int y,
                 bool &setting_change )
{
  switch ( tolower( key ) )
  {
    case 27:
      // ESCape - We're done!
      exit (0);
      break;

    case 'k':
      printf( "You hit the 'k' key\n" );
      break;

    case 0:
      switch ( sym )
      {
        case XK_Left  : 
          printf( "You hit the Left Arrow key\n" );
          break;

        case XK_Right :
          printf( "You hit the Right Arrow key\n" );
          break;
      }
      break;
  }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void reshapeCB( int width, int height )
{
  Win.width = width;
  Win.height = height;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

XVisualInfo *chooseVisual( Display *display )
{
  int attribs [ 100 ] ;
  int n = 0 ;

  // Request 24-bit color with alpha
  attribs [n++] = GLX_RGBA ;
  attribs [n++] = GLX_RED_SIZE   ; attribs [n++] = 8 ;
  attribs [n++] = GLX_GREEN_SIZE ; attribs [n++] = 8 ;
  attribs [n++] = GLX_BLUE_SIZE  ; attribs [n++] = 8 ;

  // Request 24-bit depth buffer
  attribs [n++] = GLX_DEPTH_SIZE ; attribs [n++] = 24 ;

  // Request 4 multisamples per pixel
  attribs [n++] = GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS ; attribs [n++] = 1 ;
  attribs [n++] = GLX_SAMPLES        ; attribs [n++] = NUM_SAMPLES ;

  // Request double-buffering
  attribs [n++] = GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER ;
  attribs [n++] = None ;

  return glXChooseVisual( display, DefaultScreen( display ), attribs );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void createWindow()
{
  // Init X and GLX
  Win.displayed = false;
  Display *display = Win.display = XOpenDisplay( ":0.0" );
  if ( !display )
    printf( "Cannot open X display\n" );

  int    screen   = DefaultScreen( display );
  Window root_win = RootWindow( display, screen );

  if ( !glXQueryExtension( display, 0, 0 ) )
    printf( "X Server doesn't support GLX extension\n" );

  // Pick a visual
  XVisualInfo *visinfo = chooseVisual( display );
  if ( visinfo == 0 )
    printf( "glXChooseVisual failed\n" );

  // Describe the visual
  printf( "Window Visual 0x%.2x\n", unsigned( visinfo->visualid ) );

  // Create the X window
  XSetWindowAttributes winAttr ;

  winAttr.event_mask = StructureNotifyMask | KeyPressMask ;
  winAttr.background_pixmap = None ;
  winAttr.background_pixel  = 0    ;
  winAttr.border_pixel      = 0    ;

  winAttr.colormap = XCreateColormap( display, root_win,
                                      visinfo->visual, AllocNone );

  unsigned int mask = CWBackPixmap | CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask;

  Window win = Win.win = XCreateWindow ( display, root_win, 
                                         WIN_XPOS, WIN_YPOS, 
                                         WIN_XRES, WIN_YRES, 0, 
                                         visinfo->depth, InputOutput, 
                                         visinfo->visual, mask, &winAttr ) ;

  XStoreName( Win.display, win, "My GLX Window");

  // Create an OpenGL context and attach it to our X window
  GLXContext context = glXCreateContext( display, visinfo, NULL, 1 ) ;

  if ( ! glXMakeCurrent( display, win, context ) )
    printf( "glXMakeCurrent failed.\n" );

  if ( ! glXIsDirect ( display, glXGetCurrentContext() ) )
    printf( "Indirect GLX rendering context obtained\n" );

  // Display the window
  XMapWindow( display, win );

  if ( ! glXMakeCurrent( display, win, context ) )
    printf( "glXMakeCurrent failed.\n" );

  check( "createWindow()" );

  printf( "Window Size    = %d x %d\n", WIN_XRES, WIN_YRES );
  printf( "Window Samples = %d\n", NUM_SAMPLES );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void processXEvents( Atom wm_protocols, Atom wm_delete_window )
{
  bool setting_change = false;

  while ( XEventsQueued( Win.display, QueuedAfterFlush ) )
  {
    XEvent    event;

    XNextEvent( Win.display, &event );

    if( event.xany.window != Win.win )
      continue;

    switch ( event.type )
    {
      case MapNotify:
        {
          Win.displayed = true;
          break;
        }
      case ConfigureNotify:
        {
          XConfigureEvent &cevent = event.xconfigure;
          reshapeCB( cevent.width, cevent.height );
          break;
        }
      case KeyPress:
        {
          char      chr;
          KeySym    symbol;
          XComposeStatus status;

          XLookupString( &event.xkey, &chr, 1, &symbol, &status );

          keyboardCB( symbol, chr, event.xkey.x, event.xkey.y,
                      setting_change );
          break;
        }
      case ClientMessage:
        {
          if ( event.xclient.message_type      == wm_protocols &&
               Atom( event.xclient.data.l[0] ) == wm_delete_window )
          {
            //printf( "Received WM_DELETE_WINDOW\n" );
            exit(0);
          }
          break;
        }
    }
  }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void mainLoop()
{
  // Register to receive window close events (the "X" window manager button)
  Atom wm_protocols     = XInternAtom( Win.display, "WM_PROTOCOLS"    , False);
  Atom wm_delete_window = XInternAtom( Win.display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
  XSetWMProtocols( Win.display, Win.win, &wm_delete_window, True );

  while (1) 
  {
    // Redraw window (after it's mapped)
    if ( Win.displayed )
      displayCB();

    // Update frame rate
    static timeval last_xcheck   = {0,0};
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday( &now, 0 );

    // Check X events every 1/10 second
    if ( elapsedMsec( last_xcheck, now ) > 100 )
    {
      processXEvents( wm_protocols, wm_delete_window );
      last_xcheck = now;
    }
  }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  // Init globals
  Win.width = WIN_XRES, Win.height = WIN_YRES;

  // Create context and window
  createWindow();

  // Init OpenGL
  glViewport  ( 0, 0, Win.width, Win.height ); 
  glColorMask ( 1,1,1,1 );
  glClearColor( 0,0,1,1 );
  glClear     ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

  // Go
  printf( "Valid keys: Left, Right, k, ESC\n" );
  printf( "Press ESC to quit\n" );

  mainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems here.

**First:** you haven't set up a GL viewport (e.g, using `glFrustum()` or `gluPerspective()`), so the perspective matrix isn't set up appropriately to do 3D graphics. As such, trying to draw a model in 3D won't work properly.

**Second:** The code that you've got here is written against the X11 windowing system, not Mac OS X. While it'll compile and sort-of-run on Mac OS, it will not run natively, nor will it perform particularly well. You will really want to use some interface which allows you to interface with the native Mac OS X GL implementation, such as SDL, GLUT/GLEW, or AGL.

(Keep in mind that there is no such thing as using GL "without libraries". OpenGL is itself a library, as is libX11; there's nothing at all wrong with using extra utility libraries to cut out some of the OS-specific setup and make your application easier to port.)

**Third:** You are currently learning how to use OpenGL immediate mode, which was used prior to OpenGL 3.0. Modern OpenGL — that is, OpenGL 3.0 or later, as well as OpenGL ES — uses a significantly different API which has very little in common with immediate mode. I'd strongly recommend that you skip immediate mode entirely; it's a dead technology at this point. There are a number of good tutorials out there for OpenGL 3+, including:

- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/
- http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/
- https://open.gl/

Comment: It's not necessary to use `glFrustum()` or `gluPerspective()` if you are using clip-space coordinates.

Comment: @duskwuff thank you.
 Can i make application, like this http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_(win32)/13001/   but in mac os system?  Without any libs.

Comment: nehe.gamedev.net is outdated?

Comment: From the page you linked: "This tutorial was completely rewritten January 2000." So yes, it's *incredibly* outdated. As far as libraries go, see the third paragraph of my answer — there's no such thing OpenGL as "without any libs".

Comment: @duskwuff thank you. i have  test task in the company and they are asked to do game asteroid only on opengl and c++  on ios platform:)     thank you for link, i'll read this

Comment: If you're trying to write this for iOS, you'll *definitely* need a different tutorial. iOS uses OpenGL ES, which doesn't support immediate mode at all.